# Overflow encountered in long_scalars while generating large sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am using scipy rand/random to create a m x n sized sparse array for a Neural Network experiment. I understand from documentation that sparse matrices should work for NxN where N~10^7. However the program runs into a long_scalar overflow which results in a value error inside the rand function.

```
num_rows_arr = np.arange(15096,16096,100)

for i_in in range(num_rows_arr.shape[0]):
    n_rows = num_rows_arr[i_in]
    A = random(num_rows_arr[i_in], dim_w, density=0.000075, format="csr", random_state=100)
```

[at num_rows_arr[i_in] ~ 16000 and dim_w ~ 130000 the rand function gives this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kehHO.png)

Comment: With `N=100000` I get a different error (but probably related), `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 74.5 GiB for an array with shape (10000000000,) and data type int64`,  `spare.random` has to both generate the `N*N*desity` random values, but also the random locations.

Comment: Hi, Dhaval. Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide the problematic code in your question? That'll make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: Hey Nick,  Added code for better understanding.